# Python - Can locale be used to convert numbers containing spaces?

Tags: python

I have a text file with numbers and try to convert them. The numbers are of fixed width and formatted in German style, but they have spaces between the negative sign and the digits, like `'-         15,13'`.

I could easily remove the spaces. But I'm new to `locale` and I wonder if it can be solely used to convert such numbers? In that case, how do I have to change the configuration?

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
s = '-         15,13'
f = locale.atof(s)
```

I get *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-         15.13'*

`locale.localeconv()` shows:

```
{'int_curr_symbol': 'EUR', 'currency_symbol': '€', 'mon_decimal_point': ',', 'mon_thousands_sep': '.', 'mon_grouping': [3, 0], 'positive_sign': '', 'negative_sign': '-', 'int_frac_digits': 2, 'frac_digits': 2, 'p_cs_precedes': 0, 'p_sep_by_space': 1, 'n_cs_precedes': 0, 'n_sep_by_space': 1, 'p_sign_posn': 1, 'n_sign_posn': 1, 'decimal_point': ',', 'thousands_sep': '.', 'grouping': [3, 0]}
```

The equivalent for the US:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
s = '- 234,567.89'
locale.atof(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. `locale.atof()` calls a function that removes thousands separators and sets the decimal point to a dot. The result is then passed to `float()` that raises a ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

Is it always like you only have those spaces there? If it is then you could do something like this:

```
to_be_converted = '-         15,13'

str_num1 , str_num2 = to_be_converted.replace(' ', '').split(',')

num1, num2 = int(str_num1), int(str_num2)

print(num1, num2)
#-15 13
print(type(num1), type(num2))
#<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: The strings are of fixed width, so some spaces are always there. I'm aware of using replace, but I wanted to know if it could be done woth locale alone.